# Drag object with touchesMoved along offset vector / delta?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

In the touchesMoved method, what is the math to have an object on the screen move along a dragging touch vector?  For instance, if I touch beneath my object (Y > object.y), and drag "up", I want the object to move from its current x,y location along the same vector that my finger moves.

Currently I have it working that the drag motion snaps my object to my finger's location, but sometimes my finger hits the edge of the screen before I get my object positioned correctly.

If I know my "touch down location" and the "current touch location" what is the math to determine where to move `object.position`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that you have already received the answer of figured it out yourself, but.

Assume that your object's Upper Left Corner (ULC) is at `Object.X`, `ObjectY`.
Assume that the `CGPoint` returned by `touchsBegan` is `Touch.X`, `Touch.Y`.

The offset (Delta)  will be:

- `Delta.X = Touch.X - Object.X`
- `Delta.Y = Touch.Y - Object.X`

Subtract these from each point returned by `touchesMoved` and your ULC should move as you expect rather than snapping to your finger.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into UIPanGestureRecognizer.  It's what I use when I want to accomplish something like what you are describing.

This is what I used to learn about them but then took it further in other forms: 
http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/11/draggable-buttons-labels/

Good luck!